# Loading localized resx files during TFS test runs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tfs, internationalization, mstest, resx

We are using .resx files for internationalizing our app.  Our solution and tests (mstest) works perfectly localy, and when deployed, however when we try to run the tests from Team Foundation Server (TFS) it seems the resource files are not found (all strings are always returned in en-US).

For each resource file, we have selected:

- "Embedded Resource" for the Build Action
- "Copy if newer" for the Copy to Output...
- "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator" for the Custom tool

Any suggestions on what we could do to fix this?

Comment: if its helpful to you than can you please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

- Build Action = "Content"
- Copy to output directory = "Copy always"

Please make above changes.

Comment: We made the above changes, and now our local tests and local app no longer recognize the resource files either.  It seems that when they were "Embedded Resources", the Resource Manager was able to look up the right resx files based on Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.  How do we achieve this now that we have changed them to "Content"?

Comment: please set custom tool value "GlobalResourceProxyGenerator" . Are you using global resource files?